# Donut Chart and percentage visualisation in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I wish to make :

(a) Donut chart out of Fifa World Cup 1930-2014 dataset of any dimension or measure.
(b) Any percentile data that I could display with this data in my tableau worksheet.
Please help soon.

I tried making a pie chart first and then apply a dual axis on it and then synchronise the axes but I don’t see anything related to donut chart. It just not happens.

Comment: If you simply search for Tableau donut charts you’ll find tons of examples and tutorials, including on Tableau’s own web site. If you have a specific problem where following the tutorials isn’t working, then people will need more detail about your data set and what you’ve done in Tableau to be able to help you.